# How to increment input box on add button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I want to increment my input box,
Its incrementing and also splicing but the problem is when i enter value in one box the same is replaced in the other.I think its due to ngModel.Can anyone please help me.Thnaks.

```
    <div class="form-group row text-right" *ngFor='let row of vipInput'>
    <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9" >
                <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="data.vipInput" id="email" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeVipInputs(index)">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="vipInputIncrement('val')">
             <i class=" fa fa-plus"></i>
     </button>
```

My ts,(I am using angular2)

```
 vipInputIncrement(val) {
   this.vipInput.push({'val':''});
}
removeVipInputs(k) {
  this.standardInput.splice(k,1);
}
```

Comment: I think you can just use the $index of your array to differentiate the ng-model for each element. Something like [(ngModel)]="data.vipInput[$index]"

Comment: You are binding to `data.vipInput` which doesn't depend on `row`, therefore it's the same for each row.

Comment: Hi  Gunder,how to solve this issue.

Comment: @CrazyMac,it says cannot read undefined of undefined.

Comment: @MMR Whether vipInput is an array and what is data before that?

Comment: i just declared it as an array,var vipInput = [{'val':''}]

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model should be something inside this row,

```
    <div class="form-group row text-right" *ngFor='let row of vipInput'>
    <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9" >
                <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="row.val" id="email" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeVipInputs(index)">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think it should be `row.val`, but you can decide what you want to show